# PUedo instalar SQL server en linux?como lo instalo

Tags: sql, servidor

NO puedo instalar SQL SERVER EN EL SISTEMA OPERATIVO LINUX

Comment: Realmente con la información que proporciona es muy difícil ayudar. ¿qué has intentado? ¿qué mensaje de error obtuviste?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No parece una pregunta relacionada con programación.

Comment: Me parece interesante la pregunta si la planteas así "¿Como instalar SQL Server en Linux?"

Answer (score 3):

Si puedes.

En Ubuntú por ejemplo:

- Importar llave PGP:

  `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
- Registrar el servidor en el repositorio

  `sudo add-apt-repository "$(curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list)"`
- Actualiza apt e instala el server:

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server`
- Configura tu server:

  `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`
- Verifica que el servicio está corriendo:

  `systemctl status mssql-server`

Disfruta tu servidor SQL.

Puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup)